Cache.transform-4 (The system cannot find the path specified)
When i try to create a new project in Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 version then i am getting this error message :
C:\Users\User9.gradle\caches\transforms-4\8386dfb8dc2e59da2fd43c5df69832a0\metadata.bin (The system cannot find the path specified)
I try file/invalidate caches/restart.. and rebuild project but am still getting this error message. How do I fix it?

Firstly close any open projects and close the Android Studio IDE completely.
Then delete the Corrupted Cache Manually by navigating to the folder specified in the error message:
*C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\caches\transforms-4* (In my case)
You can delete the entire transforms-4 folder to force Android Studio to regenerate the cache.
Now start up your Android Studio. It will generate new folder again, this time without any errors.
